# How to handle multiple incoming requests in nodejs that requires a token before displaying data

Tags: node.js, express

I have a middleware in my nodejs project that returns a token from my database for usage to get data from an API. This token has an expiration time on it. If the token is expired, I use a refresh token (also in my database) to get the new token. A new token then is returned with also a new refresh token and my row in the database is updated. Let's say two requests arrive at the same time to my endpoint and the token is expired at that moment. How would I make my second incoming request wait before the token is updated so it wouldn't try to make a request for a new access token when the first incoming request has already sent a request for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is what you're looking for: [How to lock critical sections of code in Node/Express with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50349077/how-to-lock-critical-sections-of-code-in-node-express-with-typescript)

Maybe you should consider lock the database table instead.